# Remove blank cells calculated from formula using excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

Have written a simple formula to pick the sl.no based on the 1st character; But I need to format the output in this below format by removing the blank cells.

Formula

=IF(LEFT(B3,1)="A",A3,"")

Expected Format
[image]

Output
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `AGGREGATE()` function. `Excel-2007` do not have Aggregate function.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$3:$A$16,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($A$3:$A$16)-ROW($A$2))/(LEFT($B$3:$B$16,1)=C$2),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

If you do not have `Aggregate()` function then use below array formula.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$3:$A$16,SMALL(IF(LEFT($B$3:$B$16,1)=C$2,ROW($B$3:$B$16)-ROW($B$2),""),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

Array formula needs to enter by pressing `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER`.

[image]

Comment: What is your excel version?

Comment: =LEFT(ADDRESS(1, ROW(A1), 4, TRUE), (ROW(A1)>26)+1)

Creates alphabet sequence vertically... How to create the same horizontally?

Comment: MS Excel for Mac... sometimes I use google sheets too...

Comment: for horizontal use `=LEFT(ADDRESS(1, COLUMN(A1), 4, TRUE), (COLUMN(A1)>26)+1)`

Comment: =IFERROR(INDEX($A$3:$A$16,SMALL(IF(LEFT($B$3:$B$16,1)=C$2,ROW($B$3:$B$16)-ROW($B$2),""),ROW(1:1))),"")

Is not compactible with Excel 2007

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you get the result you want in your output sheet, but not in the right format.  From my point of view, your "output" looks fine as it is giving you the opportunity to make a quick eye check if you have doubts about something goes wrong/looks weird.  As an alternative solution, you can just record a macro to copy the columns A to E, paste values to a new sheet and sort each column.  This will send the blank cells to the end of columns and give you the same look in your expected format.

Addition: Created [attached file](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/83e32a0eba709b2836fb1084a44a3a7c20210807163155/0cc45afe7e1521947be7edade6d49c1220210807163216/2dac9e)  after your comment.  Hit Alt + F8 to edit/add ranges to sort.

Comment: I never worked on macros...if you have a sample on how to do it using Marco's can you share the same. Thank you.